# Android never sent notifications

Tags: java, android, service, android-pendingintent

I'm making a simple light-sensor app, but as my title says, they never appear.

In my `manifest.xml`:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.Lightsensorreader">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
            android:name=".MyService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

In `MainActivity.java`, where I try to receive the data from MyService and put it on the screen:

```
private TextView lightValueTextView;
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

@Override
     protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lightValueTextView = findViewById(R.id.lightValueTV);
        sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        startService(serviceIntent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        float lightValue = sharedPreferences.getFloat("light_value", 0);
        lightValueTextView.setText("Light sensor value: " + lightValue);
    }
```

And finally the `MyService.java`, which contains the notification logic using PendingIntent and tries to use SharedPreferences.

```
private SensorManager sensorManager;
    private Sensor lightSensor;
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        lightSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT);
        sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        if (lightSensor != null) {
            sensorManager.registerListener(this, lightSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        }

        createNotificationChannel();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT) {
            float lightValue = event.values[0];

            editor.putFloat("light_value", lightValue);
            editor.apply();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return new Binder();
    }

    private void createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            String channelId = "light_sensor_notification_channel";
            String channelName = "Light Sensor Notification Channel";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, importance);
            channel.enableLights(true);
            channel.setLightColor(Color.RED);

            NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }

    private void sendNotification(String title, String message) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "light_sensor_notification_channel")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

        notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
    }
```

I have also tested the "not deprecated" methods of SharedPreferences. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the flow of data behavior that you expect, such as from the service to the activity or vice versa, and then note for us how far the data gets when you debug it and specify where exactly the data is not showing as expected?

Comment: Do you request the runtime permissions? https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/notification-permission. 
Declaring permissions in the manifest is not enough, you must also ask the user to enable them at runtime (when the application starts or the user selects to enable a feature).

Comment: @ryankuck This is the flow I planned:

1. With an intent, I start "MyService" in the "MainActivity" when the app is launched.
2. When "MyService" starts, it reads the Light Sensor.
3. After reading the data, it is shared with the "MainActivity" via SharedPreferences.
4. In the "MainActivity," I should access SharedPreferences and display it on the screen.
5. Later, a function would be implemented to notify the user when there is a significant change in the Light Sensor.

Comment: @anemomylos thanks! I add the permission and updated `pendingIntent` with "FLAG_IMMUTABLE". Working fine now.